# Using 'offline-plugin' with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, offline

I have a project with `offline-plugin` used in production. As per instructions, I have the following lines included in the sources.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  require('offline-plugin/runtime').install() // eslint-disable-line global-require
}
```

When I try to build a production version of my app, it yields an error: `Cannot find module: 'offline-plugin/runtime'. Make sure this package is installed.`

I do have `offline-plugin` included in [dev] dependencies.
My app is created with `create-react-app` so the webpack config is inside `react-scripts`.

Please advise.

Comment: you did `yarn add offline-plugin` ? to add it to your package json

Comment: nope, I installed it with npm. what would yarn do?

Comment: either is fine. if using only npm make sure you saved it. and that its in your package json. find it un Package.json under dependencies

Comment: how would it get to dev dependencies, if I did not save it?

Comment: don't put it in dev dependencies. if wont install on your server. Production builds skip dev dependencies.

Comment: this is not a dev dependency - it actually needs to be inside your source code

Comment: See https://github.com/NekR/offline-plugin
I tried moving it from dev to regular dependencies. It does nothing. Interestingly, the app builds locally. When I run it from my pipeline, the thing fails. My pipeline is pretty simple - ```RUN npm ci --only=prod --unsafe-perm

ENV SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true
ENV REACT_APP_API_URL=https://xxx.xxx.xxx

RUN npm run build
```

Comment: @tudor.gergely what do you mean by `needs to be inside your source code`?

Comment: I mean it is not a dev dependency (dev dependencies are those needed for development like webpack or  eslint but are not actually inside your prd code). Does it work running that pipeline command locally?